# can't find pinvoke dll 'dbnetlib.dll' on OS Windows CE 5.0

Tags: windows-ce

I copied 'dbnetlib.dll' in the same directory where my application is located on the target device and the app is not working. Showing the above message.

I have also copied that dll to the windows folder but it is deleted automatically. Again I tried the 'sql.ppc.wce5.armv4i.cab' installation but failed.
Can anyone send me the right solution? It will be a great help for me.

Answer (score 0):

Does the DLL work when you put it in Windows (before the reboot clears it, of course)? 
If it does then you may need to change your import attributes specifying the full path of the dll or, if your device has permanent registry, you can add your installation folder to the system path by adding it to the "SystemPath"key under HKLM\Loader.